# Как редактировать реестр с помощью Python?

Tags: python, реестр

У меня есть такой запрос к реестру

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore]
"GameDVR_Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Как мне его выполнить с помощью Python

Comment: pip install winregistry